# I get 0 for location for X,Y, Z for leftEye.center, AMD mouth.center using Spark AR

Tags: facebook, spark-ar-studio

I want to get the exact location of the mouth but I keep getting `0` for each coordinate, x,y and z.

My code:

```
const face = FaceTracking.face(0);

var tracker = Scene.root.child('Device').child('Camera').child('faceTracker0');

Patches.getPulseValue('pulseMouthOpen').subscribe(function (e) {

    var loc = face.mouth.center;

    Diagnostics.log(loc.x.pinLastValue());

});
```

Code run in AR Studio.

I want to get the exact location on the face. What am I doing wrong?